# EF6 Add Collections to model without altering DB Model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I am trying to add collection mappings to tables **without** modifying the database. I have defined a partial class so that my changes don't get wiped out when I pull down database changes. I have the generated classes:

```
// GENERATED
public partial class tran
{
    public int myNumber { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime day { get; set; }
    ...
}

// GENERATED
public partial class operatingDay
{
    public System.DateTime day { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I have created some partial classes so that I can have extra data. However, I would like to add an custom mapping outside of the database like so:

```
// MY CUSTOM CLASS
public partial class operatingDay
{
    public operatingDay()
    {
        trans = new List<tran>();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<tran> trans{ get; set; }
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything discussing how to load this collection in this scenario. I assume OnModelCreating can't be used because I am generating from the database. Is that assumption wrong and I should go the code first approach to get my collection to populate or is there another way I should be populating the collection?

Comment: So if you want the property to be there and you want it to be loaded, then why not just add it to the model? Why do you insist in managing it manually?

Comment: The database is live and customers generally take 3 to 4 quarters to update. This has to work **now** and without modifying the existing database.

Comment: Well, the model is supposed to match whatever you map on the database so that it can do the mapping. If you want to manage extra data in your POCO without updating the context then I would think you need to do this manually. Add a layer to consume the EF and have that layer populate the additional data.